# Adding count in select query

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to find a query that would give me a count of another table in the query. The problem is that I have no idea what to set where in the count part to. As it is now it will just give back a count of all the values in that table.

```
Select 
ID as Num, 
(select Count(*) from TASK where ID=ID(Also tried Num)) as Total 
from ORDER
```

The goal is to have a result that reads like

```
Num   Total
_________________
1     13
2     5
3     22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need table aliases.  So I think you want:

```
Select ID as Num, 
       (select Count(*) from TASK t where t.ID = o.ID) as Total 
from ORDER o;
```

By the way, `ORDER` is a terrible name for a table because it is a reserved work in SQL.

Comment: I understand that it is a bad name, but I just shortened its real name so I could use it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a sub query or a join (or an OVER statement.)

I think the join is clearest when you are first learning SQL

```
Select 
ID as Num, count(TASK.ID) AS Total
from ORDER
left join TASK ON ORDER.ID=TASK.ID  
GROUP BY ORDER.ID
```

Comment: In addition to having a syntax error in the `group by` clause, this query is not the same as the one in the question.  For instance, it will return the wrong values if `id` is duplicated in `order`.